# Typescript | extract from an object T all key names with values of type K

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have some interfaces/objects

```
interface Example1 {
    1: object,
    2: string,
    s: string,
    ss: string,
    as: string[],
    b: boolean,
    n: number
}
```

there is a way to get only the keys of type string that has values of type T ?

result expected:

```
type ExtractKeysOfValueType<T extends object,K> = ... // do the magic,
ExtractKeysOfValueType<Example1,string> // 's' | 'ss'
```

I already use 'Extract' to get the keys of type string, excluding symbols and numbers, but I don't know how to go on with my needs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 type ExtractKeysOfValueType<T, K> = { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends K ? I : never }[keyof T];
```

Inspired by [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23199), [try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbANIRAZwPIBmAasgDYCuEAKuBADxUA0UGAfFALxQDeUA2gEkoASwB2UANbYA9gShUAugC55ghVAgIIogCY4WUAPxQhK0RABuERFAC+fKSFnyFAbgBQ7scGsE00eGQAWzBSCABGHncoGKhwlWkAIwArCHRGaNiAJhUcJDEAcwzYqBxc-NEizJicMtKKqpLkOrzEQr4FYtjElUTpaTDkUS6Y0TNyIMTrd1tPVGlRPKgfPJV4JDRMbHxiMkoaSDpAkLDw5lbC9i4AImvXIA).This basically maps the object to a key-key object first, and keys where the related value is not of the wanted type get mapped to never:

```
 { 1: object, s: string } -> { 1: never, s: "s" }
```

Then the type of all values gets taken, resulting in `never | "s"`, and `never` gets omitted from a union, resulting in the wanted type.

Comment: ```
ExtractKeysOfValueType<Example1, string>  //"s" | "ss" | "as" | "b" | "n" | 1
```
nope :-(

Comment: Ah right, `keyof { a: never }` did not work the way I thought it would, but a similar method works: Mapping to the key itself, then making a union.

Comment: And if you want to restrict the type of your keys to only be string you can tweak it a little bit : `type ExtractKeysOfValueType<T, K> = { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends K ? I : never }[Extract<keyof T, string>];`

Comment: If anyone is looking to extract the matching entries instead of just their keys, this syntax should keep the non-matching keys out of the mapped type: `{ [I in keyof T as T[I] extends K ? I : never]: T[I] }`.